# cannot run container after commit changes

Tags: docker

Just basic and simple steps illustrating what I have tried:

1. docker pull mysql/mysql-server
2. sudo docker run -i -t mysql/mysql-server:latest /bin/bash
3. yum install vi
4. vi /etc/my.cnf -> bind-address=0.0.0.0
5. exit
6. docker ps
7. docker commit  new_image_name
8. docker run --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -d new_image_name

docker ps -a STATUS -  Exited (1)

Please let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: What does `docker logs` show for the container?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to modify an existing image, try and use (for testing) `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%`.
That would allow root login from any IP. (As seen in [docker-library/mysql issue 241](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/241#issuecomment-263011059))

```
sudo docker run --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% -d mysql/mysql-server:latest
```

The [`README`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker#mysql_root_host) mentions:

> By default, MySQL creates the `'root'@'localhost'` account.
>   This account can only be connected to from inside the container, requiring the use of the `docker exec` command as noted under Connect to MySQL from the MySQL Command Line Client.
>   To allow connections from other hosts, set this environment variable.
>   As an example, the value "`172.17.0.1`", which is the default Docker gateway IP, will allow connections from the Docker host machine.